# Resizing the window makes title go onto the border of page

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am trying to make a page with css with the little bit of skill I have been learning.  I have the title at the top of the page and it looks good but when you resize the window the title over laps the image border I have.  I just found out, that it doesn't display well in firefox.  How could I fix this? [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTM HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>This is my website</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-image:url('bg-body.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width:967px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 47px;
    left: 27%;
    color:red;
}   
.venus {
    position:absolute;
    top: 160px;
    left: 44%;
}
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 130px;    
    color:blue;

    height:500px;
    width:290px;
    background-color:#DCE1CA;
    border-top: 12px outset silver;
    border-left: 12px outset silver;
    border-right: 5px outset silver;
    border-bottom: 5px outset silver;
}
li {
    line-height:200%;
    font-size: large;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-image:none;

}
#textarea {
    position:absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 425px;    
    color:blue;
    text-align:left;
    height:500px;
    width:1149px;
    background-color:#DCE1CA;
    border-top: 12px outset silver;
    border-left: 12px outset silver;
    border-right: 5px outset silver;
    border-bottom: 5px outset silver;
}
</style>
<body>
<img src="sidebar.png" width="100%" height="2000px" class="sidebar" />
<h1>Welcome to my HTML/CSS/JavaScript Page</h1>
<img src="venus.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" class="venus" />

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>Mix of CSS & JS</li>
<li>Your Full Name</li>
<li>How Many Apples</li>
<li>Many Questions</li>
<li>Background Color</li>
<li>My Family Event</li>
<li>Images, Images</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="textarea">
Here is my story: I have been learning JavaScript and on the side I have been learning some CSS/HTML.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the link of the page?

Comment: its on my computer, don't have it on the internet yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to set your 'sidebar.png' as a background image, rather then an actual `<img>` in the html. `<img>`in the html should only be used if it's actual content, like your venus.jpg. The background is considered styling and not content.

That beeing said i would try to do something like this:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GS5VJ/)

I've put most of the explanation in the css code trying to make things clear. Perhaps it's a bit avanced, but since you say you are learning css... ;-)

The advantage of working with this kind of 'liquid' design is that the corner images will not be distorted, as they are currently. Also will your problem of the title running over the image never occurs again, wich was the goal ulmtimatly.

Comment: I have two background images, one is light green and the other one looks like a picture frame.  The frame background sits on top of the green background as a layer.`body{
 background-image:url('bg-body.jpg');
 background-repeat: repeat;
 position:fixed
 width:100%;
}
 I need to do this twice.

Comment: you can just add the green background to the body in the sample I provided. The one with picture frame is the one I assumed was called the sidebar.png in my sample. Should work without any problem.

Comment: wait, I don't think this works.  I really love the help but maybe I didn't explain my self better.  The first image bg-body has to be on repeat since its only a small picture.  The frame which is sidebar (not a good name for it I know) has to be streched to fit the page to make the page look like a picture frame.  I have it online now if you want to check it out.  bjavascript.atspace.cc/  the link for both pictures are bjavascript.atspace.cc/img/sidebar.png and bjavascript.atspace.cc/img/bg-body.jpg.  Also if you do look at it tell me what you think, I am still new to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the width to 100% instead of a fixed width, then set the background-position to fixed. See if that helps.

Comment: That worked for the firefox problem.  Is it better to work with persentage then px?

Comment: I always find it better to work with percentages as it keeps the image size relative to the window size. Don't forget to upvote if my answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

If your worried about what your page will look like when you re-size it you should be setting your heights, widths, and positions by percentage, not pixels. Setting those attributes by percentage scales them when the page re-sizes.

Ex: `background-size: 100%;`